# ecma6 prevent access to whole instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

Hi I have the following class definition:

```
'use strict'


class Human {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this._name = name || null;
    this.age = age || 'no age defined';
    this.rights = ['Human Rights'];
  }

  get this() {
    return 'access denied';
  }

  set name(name) {
    this._name = this._name ? this._name : name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
}

let me = new Human();

console.log(me); // this should return a string "access denied"
```

I thought it might be possible to define a getter for the whole instance. But this is not, or?
Does anyone know anything about that? Or is there an alternative methods to create restricted Classes?

kind regards
martin

Comment: I think here the getter is set for a member `this` inside `me` and does not refer the `me` itself. If you try `me['this']` you'll get "access denied"

Comment: When you `new` a class you are calling its `constructor` not the `get this()` (which is not a reserved ES6 class method like `constructor`).

Comment: A getter for the whole instance *is* the *constructor*. Can you specify what you mean by a *restricted class*?

Comment: @RGraham thanks for this hint. With restricted I meant, that when you "call" the instance of a class like console.log(me) you must not get the whole instance with all it's properties ({_name:'foo', _age:bar}), but only an error or some string. So one can't see the internal properties of the instance. I don't know if this makes sense at all, I just wondered if it's possible,...

Comment: What purpose would that serve? If you create an object that shouldn't be accessed, why to you create / expose it at all?

Comment: I wanted to make a Class that, when its instance is called, it does not return the internal underscored variables, but only those that are accessible by setters and getters.

Comment: @marschro: Why would you? You can achieve this by not creating underscrored properties in the first place (and using closures instead), but there's no reason to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but what you could do is put some code in a module and only export part of it.

```
 // human.js                                                     
 class SecretHuman {                                            
   constructor(name) {                                          
     this.name = name;                                          
   }                                                            
 }                                                              
 let human = new SecretHuman('Bob');                            
 export class Human {                                           
   secret() {                                                   
     console.log(`Secret human is ${human.name}`);              
   }                                                            
 }                                                              

// test.js 
import {Human} from './human';
new Human().secret();
```

Comment: So there can only be a single `SecretHuman`? And every `Human` delegates to that one?